# Dynamic regex pattern not working with special chars

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a search box in my jsp page . When the user types something in the search box a suggest list is displayed.

I have something like the below code which generates the suggest list dynamically

```
  sampleQuery.replace(new RegExp("("+query+")","ig"),'Foo'); ...(1)
```

Now the query object is the string which the user types in the search box. When I typoe in something like "?Foo" in firebug it gives javascript error on line 1. I suspect "?" is part of regular expression that's why it's throwing error.

How I can resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you want to do this in javascript or Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could beforehand either:

- escape all characters with a special meaning (such as `?*|.` etc)
- assume all none alphanumerical characters needs to be escaped.

Since the latter is easier I'll give you an example of it:

```
query = query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\\$&");
sampleQuery.replace(new RegExp("("+query+")","ig"),'Foo'); ...(1)
```

Which for the text `a?b|.c` produces `a\?b\|\.c`.

Comment: Non-**ascii** ??  I think you mean "non-alphanumeric" ... also you need a "g" modifier suffix on your regex or it'll just replace the first one.

Comment: What do you mean not working, I just tried it

Comment: try "?abc"...or may be .abc or [abc....

Comment: This is my code exactly: `var query = "?abc".replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\\$&");` 
`var q = "?abcd".replace(new RegExp("("+query+")","ig"),'Foo');`
`alert(q);`

Comment: when i use this code "query = query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\\$&");"
 in the firebug its showing me "query = query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\$&");" so the I updated the code and now it looks like

Comment: "query = query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "\\\$&");"

Answer (score 0):

See the following page that I found by searching for `javascript escape regexp` with Google:

http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/#p-6

Comment: Thnaks for your reply but that thing is not working.

Answer (score 0):

? is generally a regex character meaning "zero or one of the preceding character", and since ?Foo doesn't have a preceding character, it could be throwing your error.  You could just prepend with a \: "\?Foo".

Comment: There are a whole bunch of regex metacharacters: "[", "]", "(", ")", ".", "*", "?", "{", "}", "\", "|", "^", "$", ...